# Assign a value in forEach in Js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to define a variable in forEach scope like that:

```
let myVar;

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => myVar = key);

console.log(myVar) // this is undefined, why?
```

Comment: What is the desired behaviour? With that code you are assigning the last key in the obj (in case it have any) to myVar. When your object *obj* does not have any key nothing happens, like {}, that's why myVar remains undefined.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would avoid that: you're creating side effects that might lead to bugs that would be hard to debug. There are definitely better way to do what you want – e.g. if you want to capture the last keys of an object.

However. The code you wrote works, it would return `undefined` depending by the value of `obj`. For example:

```
let myVar;

Object.entries({}).forEach(([key, value]) => myVar = key);

console.log(myVar) // undefined
```

Where:

```
let myVar;

Object.entries({foo:1, bar:2}).forEach(([key, value]) => myVar = key);

console.log(myVar) // "bar"
```